# Switching from @types/chartjs to @types/chart.js

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I have been using the following package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chartjs` but it is now deprecated. After switching to `https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chart.js`. I get the following error.

> paydate.component.ts(42,45): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ type:
>   string; data: { labels: number[]; datasets: { fill: true; lineTension:
>   number; pointRadiu...' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'ChartConfiguration'.   Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
>       Type '{ labels: number[]; datasets: { fill: true; lineTension: number; pointRadius: number; borderWidth...' is not assignable to type
>   'ChartData'.
>         Types of property 'labels' are incompatible.
>           Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '(string | string[])[]'.
>             Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | string[]'.

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';

const myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    fill: true,
                    lineTension: 0.5,
                    pointRadius: 0, // Removes indiviual points/tooltips
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    label: 'Monthly Spending',
                    data: data,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgb(124,190,235,0.6)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(63,81,181)'
                }]
            },
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    datalabels: {
                        display: false,
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                annotation: {
                    annotations: [
                        {
                            type: 'line',
                            mode: 'vertical',
                            scaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                            value: payday,
                            borderColor: 'red',
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            // label: {
                            //     content: 'TODAY',
                            //     enabled: true,
                            //     position: 'top'
                            // }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }

        });
```

What is the problem here?

Update:

After changing label to strings i get.

```
ERROR in src/app/reports/components/paydate/paydate.component.ts(69,17): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ type: string; data: { labels: string[]; datasets: { fill: true; lineTension: number; pointRadiu...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChartConfiguration'.
  Types of property 'options' are incompatible.
    Type '{ plugins: { datalabels: { display: boolean; }; }; legend: { display: false; }; annotation: { ann...' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'annotation' does not exist in type 'ChartOptions'. Did you mean to write 'rotation'?
```

Comment: It seems that the problem comes from your labels array that is an array of numbers instead of an array of strings

Comment: After changing it to strings i still 
`ERROR in src/app/reports/components/paydate/paydate.component.ts(69,17): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ type: string; data: { labels: string[]; datasets: { fill: true; lineTension: number; pointRadiu...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ChartConfiguration'.`